# ionic 4 change ion label color when focused within ion item

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I want to change `ion-label` color inside an `ion-item` with `ion-input` when focused.

[image: img 1]

I am able to change the highlight color of `ion-item` using `--highlight-color-focused: yellow;` but unable to change the `label` color.

[image: img 2]

It is showing default color of label as primary but I want to change it as 'warning' or if required any custom color.

I've tried the following solution which is mentioned in Ionic github repository for same problem but didn't get my problem solved.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18531

Following code I have used

login.page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logoCenter">
      <ion-icon name="sync"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <h1 style="font-family: ProximaBold; color: white">Sample Application</h1>
  </div>

  <ion-grid style="margin-top: 10vh;">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="loginLabel" position="floating">Mobile No.</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="loginLabel" position="floating">Password</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-grid class="ion-padding">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center" size="12">
        <ion-button expand="full" shape="round" [routerLink]="['/home']">Submit</ion-button>
        <p style="color: white;">Forgot Password?</p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <p class="registerText">New Here? SIGN UP!</p>
</ion-content>
```

login.page.scss

```
ion-content {
    --background: linear-gradient(180deg, #2ecc71, #289c59, #1a743f);

    .logo {
        margin-top: 20%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .logoCenter {
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: linear-gradient(290deg, #31da79, #29b866);
        box-shadow:  20px 20px 60px #27ad60, -20px -20px 60px #35eb82;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        ion-icon {
            zoom: 4;
            color: white;
            animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        }
    }

    ion-item {
        --background: transparent;
        --border-color: white;
        --color: white;
        --highlight-color-focused: yellow;
    }

    ion-button {
        --background: white;
        --color: green;
    }

    .registerText {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        color: white;
        font-size: larger;
    }
}

@keyframes rotating {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code of the item so i can tell you what to do.

Comment: I've updated my post. Please check it once.

Comment: Where is the class for loginLabel. Please also add it...

Comment: ignore that, I didn't use that class. Just mentioned.

Comment: Okay inside the ion-item{.loginLabel{color:yellow}} if you make like it will not take the color?

Comment: Nope, that will give label color on normal mode. Not in focused mode

Comment: Ok , go inspect element and choose the label when focused, and in element css you will find for sure an element color related to focus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this in your page.scss

```
ion-item.item-has-focus > ion-label{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ion-item](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item)

But because of material encapsulation "--color-activated" wont work properly. The easiest way is to target ion-label directly with !important.
This is my default ion-item "scss" file.

```
.ion-item{
    --ripple-color: transparent;
    &.item-has-focus ion-label {
        color: gray !important;
    }
    ion-input {
        --padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        --padding-top: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add !important to your color it will stay focus on which color you have added

```
ion-label {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```