# Ionic change label font size on when ion-item has focus

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have tried changing the font-size of ion-label when ion-item has focus by following this example at [ionic-4-change-ion-label-color-when-focused-within-ion-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60392918/ionic-4-change-ion-label-color-when-focused-within-ion-item) but it does not work:

```
ion-item.item-has-focus > ion-label{
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Try after adding this CSS in the `global.css` instead `page.css`

Comment: @AlokMali that did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.item-has-focus .label-floating {
             transform: translateY(10px) scale(0.85);
}
```

**NOTE*** :

scale decrease as much as small font you want

but more than 0 and less than 1

Comment: Not working for me, the problem is that on focus the font size remains small.